# Slicing and dicing data from a single table

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have a table with 20M+ records and growing in SQL Server.Our users want to access this table and slice and dice the data preferably using pivot tables.

What is the best way to go about this? We don't have any tools per se in-house except for SSAS. So thinking of create a cube off a single table and giving the users an excel linked file.

Is this a good approach? Are there any other options?

TIA,
Bee

Update:

I apologize I forgot to add that I did try giving the users a Power Pivot file - but it showed up blank when they opened it (oops!). Plus they indicated that they prefer not to use power pivots.

We also have SSAS in-house but Multi-dimensional services. I was hoping to use SSAS tabular until I read that we cannot host both Tabular & MDS in one server. Hence the question.

Thanks again.

Comment: This is a very broad question.

Comment: Yes it is a good approach. I suggest SSAS tabular. Open up Visual Studio, try it, and come back with specific questions.

Comment: Take a peek at Power Pivot (Excel Add-In)

Comment: Thank you @Nick.McDermaid - I was hoping to use tabular, but we already have SSAS multi-dimensional installed & working in our environment. Read somewhere that we can't have 1 instance of SSAS running both, so wondering if I should create an MDX cube off the table directly.

Comment: You can install a seperate tabular instance but if you already have skills in mutli dimensional then that seems to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The excel option is the only best option. You can slice and dice in pivot table easily.

Comment: It's the only best option? Is it the only option or best option? Pivot is simple in Excel, and powerful, but can you elaborate on your "answer" on why it's the best / or only option

Comment: Excel is not going to handle 20M+ records. Only if you put some kind of cubing mechanism in the middle